# How to call promises in a loop

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, q

I have to call some code asynchronous code in a loop. I tried using promises, but the iterator is not being bound as I would expect. 
When I do something like

```
for n in [1,2,3]
  console.log "PRINT:" + n
  Q()
  .then =>
    console.log "PRINT:" + n
```

It prints

```
PRINT:1
PRINT:2
PRINT:3
PRINT:3
PRINT:3
PRINT:3
```

I understand that this is because the loop is executed first and then the promises start to resolve. I'd like to know how to get each print inside the promise chain to be called with a different value of n (or any way to get a promise chain to execute for different values in an array).

EDIT: as requested in the comments, my code in JS looks like this

```
var n, _i, _len, _ref;

_ref = [1, 2, 3];
for (_i = 0, _len = _ref.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
  n = _ref[_i];
  console.log("PRINT:" + n);
  Q().then((function(_this) {
    return function() {
      return console.log("PRINT:" + n);
    };
  })(this));
}
```

Comment: Translate your problem to javascript please

Comment: Great, I will answer soon :)

Comment: @dseminara: No need, the problem and solution are already known :-)

Comment: Just in case, the solution is to chain promises in the for loop, instead of simply creating new ones, something like that:

var promise = Q(); for (...) { promise = promise.then(...) }